# gravity form disappears with variation selection in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using woocommerce with Mystile. I have variations of a product but also need the product customized. I have not figured out a way to handle product customization to meet my needs with woocommerce so I am also using gravity forms.

The problem I am experiencing is that when a single product is displayed and the user clicks on the variation option “choose an option” the add to cart disappears (I understand this is by design –which makes sense) but the gravity form on the page **also** disappears. I would like the gravity form **not** disappear. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?
Thanks.